# Process.Start can't find an existing file

Tags: c#, .net, file, process, io

- I have the path of an executable file (`C:\Test\n4.TestConsole.exe`).
- `File.Exists(path)` returns `true`.
- `File.OpenRead(path)` gets me its stream with no problem.
- `Process.Start(path)` throws a `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception` with this message:

> The system cannot find the file specified.
>   
>   What am I doing wrong?

<sub>Windows 8 Professional x64 - .NET Framework 4.5</sub>

---

**Edit:** Here is the code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I put a breakpoint here and verify the Path's value is
        // C:\Test\n4.TestConsole.exe.

        // File.Exists returns true.
        MessageBox.Show(File.Exists(Path));

        // File.OpenRead doesn't throw an exception.
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(Path)) { }

        // This throws the exception.
        Process.Start(Path);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the file you are trying to execute? Is it 'executable'? Can you show the value of path?

Comment: @WouterdeKort: A console application. It opens and waits for an input when I double-click it. The path is: `C:\Test\n4.TestConsole.exe`

Comment: What is the value of path? You need to use the full file path if the file is not in System32

Comment: @WouterdeKort: I updated the question with path.

Comment: Are you using :- @"C:\Test\n4.TestConsole.exe"

Comment: It could be that the missing file is a required dependency e.g. a DLL. Does TestConsole.exe run from a command prompt?

Comment: @Derek: Yes, of course. The code compiles, `File.Exists(path)` returns `true`, when I copy the path to the Windows Explorer's address bar and hit enter, I see the console.

Comment: @Rich: Yes, I can run it from a command prompt.

Comment: Show some code. That would help!

Comment: What is the calling code? WinForms? ASP.NET?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: WinForms: `Click` event of a `Button`.

Comment: @Derek: Nothing to show, really. It is a plain WinForm form with just a `Button` on it. I call `Process.Run(path)` in that button's Click event.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work, so there could be something wrong in the code. I cant just assume that you have it right, it could be something very simple.

Comment: Something else is the problem. Maybe `path` is not what you think by the time `Process.Start(path)` is executed. Show us the full code as Derek already asked and maybe we can find the problem. Did you also try to debug and made sure `path` is what you expect it to be?

Comment: @Shadow: Alright, will update the question in a minute.

Comment: Is it a windows store app or a desktop app?

Comment: Can you run at a command prompt from the same directory as the WinForms app's current directory? Have you tried running cmd /k C:\Test\n4.TestConsole.exe instead of running directly?

Comment: @zmbq: It is a desktop application.

Comment: It also works from the Process.Start() call? (I mean running cmd.exe /k etc).

Comment: @Rich: Yes! `Process.Start("cmd", "/k " + path)` works. I have no idea why does that happen but that does the trick and I'll accept if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a missing DLL or other dependency. You might like to compare the PATH environment variable when you run it directly via `Process.Start(exe_path)` and when you run it via `Process.Start("cmd", "/k " + exe_path)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Test";
    psi.FileName = "n4.TestConsole.exe";
    Process.Start(psi);
}
```